# How do I connect to IRC using Emacs?

Tags: networking, irc

I want to get onto the #Emacs channel on Freenode. How do I do it?

Comment: May I suggest slightly more research before posting a question, please?  The first hit on a google search for "emacs irc" returns [EmacsWiki: Internet Relay Chat](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InternetRelayChat), and the second returns [EmacsWiki: ERC](http://www.emacswiki.org/ERC).

Comment: @Dan Right now I am trying to ask questions that relate specifically to emacs as per [this](http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68/not-yet-ready-for-public-beta?cb=1). I will try to ask more detailed ones though I do believe this kind of question does belong, though possibly as a community wiki listing the alternatives for connecting to IRC.

Comment: This question is perfectly on topic here, but the private beta is the time to show interesting or difficult questions. Please don't flood the site with trivial ones right now.

Comment: @Malabarba, alright. I will ask more complicated ones in the future :). I just want to help get this into public beta.

Comment: Private beta is over and this question looks to me like the very one place where a canonical answer should be given. I think it deserves more love. Also: [Embrace the non-Googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers).

Answer (score 13):

`M-x erc` is built in and works well. You want to join `irc.freenode.net`; the initial login is pretty self-explanatory. Then, type `/join #emacs` from the main IRC prompt.

Answer (score 2):

There is also circe, but you have to install it through melpa

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs 22 or later just type `M-x irc` to start [rcirc](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/rcirc). Using the default configuration will connect to Freenode and join #rcirc. If you don't want to use the default configuration, type `C-u M-x irc` instead. Otherwise you can [configure rcirc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/rcirc/Configuration.html#Configuration) in your init file.